# Find the number of irrational terms in the binomial expansion of $(3^{1/5}+7^{1/3})^{100}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

After expanding the above term binomially, I can well guess that the majority terms are irrational, but i'm unable to find any proper method of solving this sum, after repeated trials.

Please help

**Thank You**

Comment: Cute disguise for a Diophantine equation.

Comment: Each of the $101$ terms in the expansion has the form ${100\choose i}{\sqrt[5]{3}}^i{\sqrt[3]{7}}^{100-i}$. Such a term is irrational unless $i$ is a multiple of $5$ and $100-i$ is a multiple of $3$. Can you go from there?

Comment: @BrianTung: I'd say a cute disguise for a Chinese Remainder.

Comment: @Pedro: to-MAY-to, to-MAH-to? :-)

Comment: @BrianTung: Fair enough :-). Although a "Diophantine Equation" sounds scarier, somehow.

Comment: Will the no of irrational terms be 93?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The binomial sum is $$\sum_{k = 0}^{100} {100 \choose k} 3^{k/5}7^{(100-k)/3},$$
and the rational terms are exactly the integer terms, i.e., when both $k/5$ and $(100-k)/3$ are integers.

Comment: @InfinitelyUndefined Have you learned abound congruences? You need to solve the system $k \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ and $k \equiv 100 \pmod 3$ for $k$, by using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: No i haven't.Ok i'll try to learn it.There i wanted to mean (100-6-3+2).Sorry for that.

Comment: @InfinitelyUndefined: I assumed this was a problem in a class involving congruences and Chinese Remainder. However, this particular case is simple enough to allow for simpler solutions. For instance, one can write $k = 5m$ and ask when $100 - k = 5(20 - m)$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: **Thank you**,& something tells me that my previous logic was also not entirely wrong.**3|(100-k)** & **5|k**.So,the no **(100-k)** should be such that it is divisible by both 3 & 5 i.e **15**. [otherwise 'k' will not be divisible by 5,the vise-versa is impossible as you said that we cannot always find such 'm' such that **3|(100-15m)**] .There are 6 such (100-k)'s  which are divisible by 15.(15,30,45,60,75,90).Also (100-k) can be 0.So,from here 'k' corresponds to be(85,70,55,40,25,10,100 respectively.) which are all divisible by 5.So,there are 7 rational terms & (100-7)=93 irrational terms.

Comment: @InfinitelyUndefined: You're right, well spotted! You can argue that $100 - k$ must be one of the seven multiples of $15$, hence there are $7$ rational terms. Note, however, that this works because $100$ is a multiple of $5$ (if you want to play around with the problem, you can try to see what happens if the exponent is $101$ instead).

Comment: Ok,Thank you..I'll try with 101..